# Truly driverless printer scanner

Tags: printer, scanner

I'm tired of losing support of functionality in my printer/scanner due to new operating system versions.
I'm looking for a printer/scanner that can work with no drivers. I have read that this can be achieved with an embedded web server that has full printing and scanning capabilities.
I haven't been able to find proper documentation on the web server capabilities of each printer model.
Does anyone know which printer models have a web server with these capabilities?
Alternatively, can anyone suggest other ways to have a printer/scanner without needing to install drivers?

Comment: And how do you imaging sending a print job to this server?

Comment: Upload a PDF...

Comment: In this case, you might wanna change your title to "Printer/Scanner that can work purely over the HTTP interface".  It would not be driverless, as the drivers would be managed by the HTTP interface.  I haven't heard of such a thing, but I never paid attention, so I'll be on the lookout for it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I didn't make up the term "driverless", I found that it's used to refer to exactly the thing I'm interested in (try googling "driverless printer"). I think it's a reasonable way to convey the fact that no drivers are needed on the main user device. I grant you that a web server is just one possible solution, I edited the question to reflect that.